# How to convert an Adobe EPS file to PDF programmatically using C# classes alone?

Tags: c#, eps

Is there a way to convert EPS file to PDF purely using C# classes and without using any third-party tools? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score -1):

Only write converter by your own. Read format specs and write.